# Rails validations are not being run on nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation, nested-attributes

I'm on Rails 3.2.8 and Ruby 1.9.3.

I'm having trouble figuring out why the validations on the nested attributes are not being run or returning any errors. When I submit the form with nothing filled in, I get errors back for the parent model (User), but not for the child model (Account).

In my code below, I have a User model which has_one owned_account (Account model), and an Account model that belongs_to an owner (User model). The Account model has a text field for a subdomain string.

It seems that when I submit the form without including the subdomain field, the validations on the Account model are not run at all. Any ideas on how I can get the validations here working? Thanks in advance for any help or pointers.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :owned_account_attributes
  has_one :owned_account, :class_name => 'Account', :foreign_key => 'owner_id'

  validates_associated :owned_account
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owned_account, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['subdomain'].blank? }
end
```

**account.rb**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :owner_id, :subdomain
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User'

  validates :subdomain, 
    :presence => true, 
    :uniqueness => true,
    :format => { ...some code... }
end
```

**new.haml**

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  ... User related fields ...
  = f.fields_for :owned_account_attributes do |acct|
    = acct.label :subdomain
    = acct.text_field :subdomain
  = submit_tag ...
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.save
      ...
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method to the User model. Like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :owned_account_attributes, # other user attributes 
  has_one :owned_account, :class_name => 'Account', :foreign_key => 'owner_id'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owned_account
  validates_associated :owned_account
end
```

Then you should see validation errors pertaining to the nested model on the parent model (User):

```
["Owned account subdomain can't be blank", "Owned account is invalid"]
```

**EDIT**

The culprit turned out to be the `:reject_if` bit in the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` line that effectively instructed Rails to ignore nested account objects if the subdomain attribute was blank (see discussion in comments)

Comment: Thanks catching that Andrea. It was actually a mistake that I left it out of my posting. I've made an update. I do have it in my User model along with a :reject_if statement to test whether the subdomain text field is empty. However, when I submit the form with no entries and check the errors on the User model, I don't get anything for Owned Account, only the errors for the User model. I've also tried passing owned_account as an object to fields_for, or adding a validates_presence_of, but I can't get any errors for the empty subdomain string. Any additional thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, your :reject_if is actually causing the nested account details to be ignored altogether. What you have there basically translates to "Reject the nested account (don't validate or save it) if the subdomain attribute is blank". So just remove the :reject_if bit part and you should see the validations.

Comment: Yes, you are correct and that was the problem. Removing reject_if solved this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I have nested attributes added to my form but without the `validates_associated ...` the validation never works, even though I have `reject_if` removed, is validates_associated required?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the nested form is generating fields for owned_account_attributes, which is not an association, instead of owned_account.
Have you tried doing a User.create with nested attributes on the rails console to see if it works there?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem was with the reject_if statement I had on my accepts_nested_attributes_for. It was rejecting the nested model when the subdomain string was empty.